# Dropzonjs IOS Support

Tags: dropzone.js

What kind of IOS support does this plugin have.  I just tried it the dropzonejs demo on their website on my mobile safari and it doesn't work, however Mobile Chrome worked fine.

Any luck getting this to work on mobile safari as well?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like this is a bug that shipped out with ios8. I suspect it will be fixed in 8.0.1 or whatever.

http://blog.uploadcare.com/post/97884147203/you-cannot-upload-files-to-a-server-using-mobile-safari

Comment: I'm on 8.1 and it's still not working - is there a fix?

Comment: It works fine after 8.0.1 Your problem is unrelated.

Comment: I'm using iOS 9.3.1 and when i tap the dropzone box nothing happens.

Comment: I discovered that the issue was that I had to hold my finger down longer to get it to work.  I was tapping too fast apparently.

Comment: anybody find a solution for this

Comment: @Shareque Dude, this was patched on main release months after. It's now 6 years later haha.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this workaround.

`if (/(iPad|iPhone|iPod)/g.test(navigator.userAgent)) {
       var dz = $(".dz-hidden-input").detach();
       $(dz).css({
                'position':'relative',
                'visibility':'visible'
       });
       $("#div-around-dropzone").prepend(dz);
    }`